# D3 bar plot with double x Axis for month and year

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar plot with two x-axis, one for the months and another for the year as shown in the picture below. I tried to find examples but couldn't find any and I don't really know where to start.

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can call x-axis as many times you want. As illustrated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233847/dual-x-axes-for-line-graphs-in-svg)
you can call it multiple times. For using separate tick values, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173533/customize-the-d3-month-or-year-tick-format) explains year / month tick formatting for axes. Hope these will help.

Comment: Thanks canozsoy for the input. It clearly a good starting point.